# Java / Spring exception thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, program-entry-point

I'm currently learning a new language on my own : Java with Spring.

I've managed to create the parent and dependencies for the project in the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>tech.benjaminpradon</groupId>
  <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>benjaminpradon</name>


 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<!-- Version -->
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
</project>
```

I have also created the Spring Application run programm:

```
 package springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LearningJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LearningJava.class, args);

    }

}
```

However, when I try to run it, I get an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at springboot.LearningJava.main(LearningJava.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

I thought I needed to create a ResourcesController (RestController).
So, I created one:

```
package springboot.hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String Hi() {
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

But, It doesn't change a thing.

As I'm a newbee, I really need help.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to delete .m2 folder and re-run again or updated dependencies again.

Comment: It seems like you're missing dependencies. Can you try with a different dependency version or try https://stackoverflow.com/a/47977396/4100453 . Add the build information to the pom file

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've just tried to add the build to the pom file but still not working.  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Comment: What dependencies could I be missing? @AlexanderFalk

Comment: @mallikarjun Thanks - I deleted the .m2 folder and updated the project. It's working!  Cheers

Comment: I observed this problem while updating my project to spring-boot-2. Maven unable download the dependencies or downloaded dependencies are corrupted. So I deleted older spring versions from .m2 and built the project which downloaded the latest jars. Problem is few projects whose dependencies are different version am unable to get them. So I configured separate maven path for spring-boot2 projects in my local folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mallikarjun mentionned, I should

> delete .m2 folder and re-run again or updated dependencies again

Comment: why? It's the anwser.

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry. In the reviewing page you can only see one answer. It sounded like an response to an answer to me.