# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA. My SpringBoot startup has this error

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at com.atguigu.crowd.Atcrowdfunding10MemberMysqlProviderApplication.main(Atcrowdfunding10MemberMysqlProviderApplication.java:14)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Please provide your project dependency (pom.xml for maven, build.gradle for gradle or something else), as such problem is usually due to wrong version of dependencies.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65331448/8203759

Comment: @Konstantin Annikov thank you very much . I solve that problem. It's really due to   wrong version of dependencies.