# Maven: Cannot find or load main class

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, deployment

I made my first Spring application and now I need to package it in a jar file for deployment. Inside `pom.xml`, I specified the `maven-jar-plugin` in order to automatically create the manifest file for my jar, like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>bg.sofia.uni.fmi.melodify.MelodifyApplication</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then I package it using the package button inside the Intellij Maven view and it produces a jar file successfully. When I run the jar file with `java -jar <path/to/jar/file.jar>`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class bg.sofia.uni.fmi.melodify.MelodifyApplication
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner
```

My `MelodifyApplication` class looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MelodifyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MelodifyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Application started ...");
    }
}
```

I tried writing my own Manifest.mf file and creating the jar myself like this:

```
jar cfm Melodify.jar Manifest.mf -C Melodify/src/main/java/ .
```

but I got the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: I tried deleting the `.m2` folder and reloading the maven project. This didn't work for me.

Comment: I dont quite remember, but i believe that when it comes to packaging spring applications spring-boot-maven-plugin was one of the go-to's because just regular packaging would cause problems when running (missing classes or classpath issues). You could check that plugin out, it should make things easier for you

Comment: See this Spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/howto-build.html

Comment: You are using Spring Boot and are working around it. Ditch the `maven-jar-plugin` and add `spring-boot-maven-plugin` instead.

Comment: You are amazing. It worked! I feel so relieved after spending hours yesterday trying to fix this. Would some of you, kind people, like to write your answer as an answer, instead of a comment, so I can mark it as accepted and upvote it?

Comment: I just encountered another problem. My application worked just fine. When I packaged it, and ran the jar, I encountered exceptions I haven't seen before. Even if I try to run it from the IDE, I still get this exception. It wasn't like this before I packaged the jar. Any ideas?

Comment: Please submit a new question regarding the new errors you are facing with details.

Comment: @BIBOOunit1998X I was missing the `-parameters` flag inside the configuration for the `maven-compiler-plugin`. I am not sure how I could run my project without it previously and why I need it now, but the important thing is everything is fine now. Thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to follow the pattern what [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) does:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

**Optional:** Defining the `spring-boot-starter-parent` makes your life easier - it handles dependency management for you. Background: see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305016/what-does-spring-boot-starter-parent-exactly-do-in-pom-file).

Finally, instead of [Maven Jar Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/), use [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/):

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

With this setup, issuing:

```bash
mvn package
```

...should build you a proper *uber-jar* of your Spring Application:

```bash
java -jar target/spring-sandbox-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.1)

2024-01-10T09:52:00.671+01:00  INFO 98109 --- [           main] c.g.t.s.SpringSandboxApplication         : Starting SpringSandboxApplication using Java 17.0.3 with PID 98109 (/Users/tamas/git/spring-sandbox/target/spring-sandbox-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by tamas in /Users/tamas/git/spring-sandbox)
...
```

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned previously in the comments under my question, using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` was the decisive step in solving my issue. Have a great day!